# Vulnerability in restricted eval

Tags: web-application, php, appsec

Is it possible to exploit this code?

```
eval ("\$RequestVariables = \$_REQUEST;");
```

or

```
eval ("\$ServerVariables = \$_SERVER;");
```

I know if `$_REQUEST` or `$_SERVER` wasn't an array and if it was a string or int it was possible to exploit it, but in this case its an array. Is it still possible to exploit this code?

Comment: How would you exploit it if `$_REQUEST` was a string or int?

Comment: I did it like this eval ("$test = $something") and if something was 1111 ; echo 'pwned'; it executed my echo

Comment: The bigger question is why the heck this is being eval'ed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, that's not exploitable.

All variables in the string you're passing to `eval()` are `\`-escaped, so they don't get expanded. This means you're always literally evaluating...

```
$RequestVariables = $_REQUEST;
```

...which is just an ordinary assignment without any possibility to inject your own code.

> What if they were not `\`-escaped?

In that case you're still out of luck because `$_REQUEST` and `$_SERVER` are guaranteed to be arrays, and the string representation of an array is always just `Array`, not displaying any contained values.

Comment: Thanks. What if they were not \-escaped?

Comment: @JohnDoes In that case I *think* you're still out of luck because `$_REQUEST` and `$_SERVER` just get expanded to `"Array"`, giving you no chance to get your own payload inside the string.